# React upload csv file to S3 using react-aws-s3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a react app where a user can upload a file to an S3 bucket.

I have a react component that can successfully get the file from the user. And a button that calls a function where I can send the file to S3.

I am using `react-aws-s3` because this is going to be the only direct functionality I am going to need so I didn't want to install the whole `aws-sdk` package and bloat my application.

Now I have followed a few different blogs/instructions on how to do this ([like this one](https://blog.devgenius.io/upload-files-to-amazon-s3-from-a-react-frontend-fbd8f0b26f5)) but haven't been able to get the file to upload.

My upload code looks like this (and I will be moving the access keys to env variables):

```js
const S3_BUCKET = ...
const REGION = ...
const ACCESS_KEY = ...
const SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ...

const config = {
    bucketName: S3_BUCKET,
    region: REGION,
    accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
};

const ReactS3Client = new S3(config);
// the name of the file uploaded is used to upload it to S3
ReactS3Client.uploadFile(datasheet, datasheet.name)
    .then((data) => console.log(data.location))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

I have enabled public access, added the bucket policy to this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicListGet",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3::: my bucket name",
                "arn:aws:s3::: my bucket name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and the cors policy to this:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2",
            "ETag"
        ]
    }
]
```

But when I try and upload the file I get a 400 bad request response.

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
type: "cors"
url: ...
[[Prototype]]: Response
```

It says it's `type: cors` but I have cors fully enabled right? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I followed the tutorial that you pasted I managed to upload the file to s3. It works with your cors policy as well.
Here are a couple of things to check:

1. The network tab and the actual response from S3 [image] This will give you more information on the actual problem that you are having

2. Your bucket policy allows only List and Get, but in the tutorial, it's **s3:*** So your user must have permission to upload files to this bucket.
3. Double check the upload logic in the demo it's like this:

```
    const handleFileInput = (e) => {
        setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0]);
    }

    const uploadFile = async (file) => {
        const ReactS3Client = new S3(config);
        // the name of the file uploaded is used to upload it to S3
        ReactS3Client
        .uploadFile(file, file.name)
        .then(data => console.log(data.location))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
    return <div>
        <div>React S3 File Upload</div>
        <input type="file" onChange={handleFileInput}/>
        <br></br>
        <button onClick={() => uploadFile(selectedFile)}> Upload to S3</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: I was using a service class for my upload call functionality. I tried just doing it in the component like you have, but still get the same problem. So I decided to delete and recreate the S3 bucket. I added the bucket and cors policies, made it public access, and now I'm getting `Access to fetch at '....amazonaws.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Never mind. Looks like the updated cors policy need like a half hour to catch up. I tried it again and just get the same error as before.

Comment: Also, I am using the access keys for the IAM user that I used to create the bucket so I assume I have a write accessibility?

Comment: I feel a bit silly now. I thought I had ACLs enabled. Enabling that fixed everything. Thank you!